# Is there any way of replacing components symbols systematically in KiCad?

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, kicad

I'm drawing a schematic in KiCad which has a lot of capacitors and resistors. Now i realised that for the sake of tidyness and to make it easier to read it would be nice to have those caps and resistors replaced for the smaller size symbols. 
Is there any way to do that without having to go through them one by one?

Comment: Do you mean symbol (schematic) or footprint?

Answer (score 2):

**Replacing symbols**

Although KiCad has no specific tool to perform that, you can try the following. Let's say you want to replace all resistor symbols `R` with a photo resistor, whose symbol is `R_PHOTO`.

Just open your schematic file `project.sch` with a text editor, replace all instances of `Device:R` with `Device:R_PHOTO`, save and close it. Just make sure that the replacement's symbol has the same amount of connections and match the replaced symbol. For resistors and non-polarized capacitors should work just fine.

**Replacing footprints**

You can use a python library `kifield` for that as follows:

1. Install the library

`pip install kifield`

2. Copy all fields of a schemactic `project.sch` to a `csv` file

`kifield -x .\project.sch -i design_fields.csv`

3. The table should look like the following:

```
Refs,datasheet,footprint,value
C1,~,Capacitor_SMD:C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.05x0.95mm_HandSolder,22u
C2,~,Capacitor_SMD:C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.05x0.95mm_HandSolder,1n
C3,~,Capacitor_SMD:C_0603_1608Metric_Pad1.05x0.95mm_HandSolder,100n
D1,~,custom-footprints:SMA_DO-214AC,SS14
D2,~,LED_SMD:LED_1206_3216Metric_Pad1.42x1.75mm_HandSolder,YELLOW
```

4. Replace let's say the `0603` cap size with an appropriate `0805` one using the `replace all` function of any text editor. save and close the csv file.

```
Refs,datasheet,footprint,value
C1,~,Capacitor_SMD:R_0805_2012Metric_Pad1.15x1.40mm_HandSolder,22u
C2,~,Capacitor_SMD:R_0805_2012Metric_Pad1.15x1.40mm_HandSolder,1n
C3,~,Capacitor_SMD:R_0805_2012Metric_Pad1.15x1.40mm_HandSolder,100n
D1,~,custom-footprints:SMA_DO-214AC,SS14
D2,~,LED_SMD:LED_1206_3216Metric_Pad1.42x1.75mm_HandSolder,YELLOW
```

5. Import it back into KiCad

`kifield -x design_fields.csv -i .\project.sch`

Now your footprints should be updated

Comment: The change footprint feature is now built into PCBNew, you don't need any external scripting.

Comment: @awjlogan I was not aware of it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I'm also afraid the schematic change by find/replace doesn't work - that was my first thought too, but it only works if both of the symbols' connection nodes are in the same place.

Comment: @awjlogan What do you mean by *both of the symbols's connection nodes are in the same place*? I might have overlooked something, but I ran a small test and it seemed to work. I had some resistors replaced in a schematic of my own.

Comment: It only works (completely) if the symbols are the same length, ie if you put the two symbols side by side the pins are in the same position. If they're not, then the wires will not be connected anymore. KiCAD's netlist is generated from the wire coordinates, not a logical mapping. So, to clarify, it does _replace_ the symbol, but you'll have to go back and stitch any dangling wires.

Comment: @awjlogan got it. You are right. Just double checked it. Thanks again.

Comment: KiCad version 5 has the library reference editor which does exactly what OP wants. It allows you to change the symbol referenced. No need for a text editor

Comment: Similarly, for footprint assignments. Use either the assign footprint tool or the field editor (both found in the tools menu) of version 5.

Comment: Although not up-to-date I don't understand why someone would downvote an answer which conditionally works.

Comment: @vtolentino Your solution requires a deep understanding of the KiCad file format to ensure one does not break the project. And you don't even bother to tell the reader that they really should consider to first make a backup in case they screw this up. Plus the footprint assignment tool was in KiCad since before version 4 so there really is no excuse not to know that thing.

Comment: @vtolentino your solution also does not take into account the behaviour of the cache library system nor does it handle the timestamps.

Comment: Thank you gus for the replies, i did it with the library reference editor as @Rene Pöschl mentioned and it worked perfectly. Of course they don't  fit so i have to lengthen the wire lines. that's easier than having to replace all of them and add the values of each component. thanks again for you help

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool in eeschema:
tools -> edit symbol library references.

This allows you to change the referenced symbol for symbols. However, be aware that if the pin positions of the two symbols differ then you will need to fix up the schematic afterwards.

---

For changing footprint assignments on mass use either the assign footprint tool (you can select multiple symbols to change with shift click) or the field editor. Both are found in the tools menu.